# Cakephp foreach data for options in select (form)

Tags: cakephp, foreach, html-select

in my project I have database

- "Products" hasAndBelongsToMany "Sizes"
- "ProductsSize" belongsTo "Products"
- "ProductSize" belongsTo "Size"

In ProductsSize, one product_id may have many size_id.

hence, i want to do a form that have a select type input that list down all the size_id where the product_id = $id.

What i have done is:

in controller:

```
$size = $this->Product->ProductsSize->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('ProductsSize.product_id' => $id), 
    'fields' => array('ProductsSize.size_id'),
));
```

in view:

```
<?php echo $this->form->create('Cart', array('action' => 'add')); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('size_id', array('label' => 'Size', 'options' => $size)); ?>
```

then i got error: Undefined index: ProductsSize

but when i put foreach, the data shown:

```
<?php foreach ($size_apparel as $size): ?>
<?php echo $size['ProductsSize']['size_id'];?><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

can anyone please help me to do the foreach in options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an invalid array for the options. You are requesting:

```
$size = $this->Product->ProductsSize->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('ProductsSize.product_id' => $id), 
    'fields' => array('ProductsSize.size_id'),
));
```

What you should be requesting is:

```
$size = $this->Product->ProductsSize->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('ProductsSize.product_id' => $id),
));
```

This will return the options for the form field in the format it expects which is:

```
array(
  {id} => {size},
  {id} => {size},
  {id} => {size},
  {id} => {size},
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to say

```
<?php echo $this->form->input('size_id', array('label' => 'Size', 'options' => $size)); ?>
```

note 'options' instead of 'value'

Comment: hey thanks for the answer..its a mistake from copy paste..but i already use options.. and still got the Undefined index: ProductsSize error.

Comment: Is it supposed to be "ProductSize" instead of "ProductsSize" in your codes?

Answer (score 0):

$List = Set::classicExtract($size, '{n}.ProductSize.product_id');

$List will contain key value(ProductSize.product_id) pair.

OR you can change your query as

```
$size = $this->Product->ProductSize->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('ProductSize.product_id' => $id),
));
```

Hope it will work for you